# Using Regex to only grab the first match of a pattern

Tags: regex

I've been looking for the answer to this question and I have not gotten a clear answer.

I have the text:

> MSI GeForce **GTX 1080** Ti DirectX 12 GeForce **GTX 1080** Ti GAMING X 11G

I am using the regex

```
GTX +?\d+
```

that returns the results `GTX 1080` twice

I would like to only grab one match and exit.

Is there a regex that would do this? Or do I need to use the regex framework for the language I am using?

Comment: You _could_ theoretically really only find the first match by using a negative lookback, but it's probably much easier to use whatever you're using right now and just take the first result.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? If you search without global flag you would only get the first match eg in JS regex.

Comment: This depends entirely on what language and framework you are using. The most regex neutral thing you can do is put your pattern in a capture group, and then just use `[\s\S]*$` to consume the rest of the input.

Comment: Eventually in my ETL pipeline I will be using re from python, but right now I am trying to eliminate a step by using regex on a string right from an data extractor tool. Terza + @Jim Simson the method you suggested got me what I wanted as well but the data extractor tool I was working with did not have the intelligence to understand capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grabs just one match and exits. For clarity, it grabs the last match, but it does what You want it to do. Tested on regex101.com

```
GTX +?\d+(?!.*GTX +?\d+.*$)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. In the context for what I am trying to do. This works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`(GTX \d+)[\s\S]*`    [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3lB0vo/2)

This method will isolate your first match into a capture group which you can retrieve using your language of choice. You didn't specify one, so I'll just leave it at that.
Here's what's going on:

The parentheses around your query `(GTX \d+)` place it into the first (and only) capture group.

The bracketed group that follows `[\s\S]` will match any single character in the set. Since all characters must either be a whitespace (`\s`) or not a whitespace (`\S`) the result is that anything goes.

Finally, the `*` quantifier at the end will match zero or more consecutive characters in the preceding set, ensuring that the remainder of your string is consumed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works well, This will be how I use it later in the ETL pipeline I am building

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with the rest of your project!